# what the meaning of "value" in eigen_centrality?

Tags: r, igraph

Can anybody tell me the calculation of "value" in eigen_centrality? How the value is calculated? Very thanks.

For example, in step 2, I have got the 5 eigen value of the total of 5 nodes.

```
library(igraph)
e1 <- eigen_centrality(g1,directed = TRUE)
eigenvalue[[i]] <-e1[["value"]]
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://igraph.org/r/doc/eigen_centrality.html  It explains that it is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks, but the calculation of the value doesn't available.

Comment: Eigenvector centrality is just the eigenvector of the adjacency matrix corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. igraph uses ARPACK for the calculation.